# Can't copy files to the Products Directory in Xcode

Tags: ios, bash, xcodebuild

I need to replace the `Copy Files` build phase with the manual copy files via `Run Script` build phase.

Copy Files stage looks like this now:

[image: copy phase]

The replacement script looks this way:

[image: script]

but the destination dir is not correct. What is the correct absolute path for the `Products Directory`? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `Products Directory` is a `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` in xcodebuild

Comment: @Andrew I think this is the complete and the only answer for my question, no?